# Trying to update value of a reference when onWrite?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to update value of /myotherstuff when there's a write in /mystuff. But the code below doesn't do that. What should I change?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/mystuff')
.onWrite(event => { 

   admin.database().ref('/myotherstuff').update(null);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/mystuff').onWrite(event => { 
    return admin.database().ref('/myotherstuff').set(null);
});
```

As opposed to the [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#set) method, [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#update) can be use to selectively update only the referenced properties at the current location (instead of replacing all the child properties at the current location).

In your case instead of set to null you can remove the child :

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/mystuff').onWrite(event => { 
    return admin.database().ref('/myotherstuff').remove();
});
```

[Firebase Cloud Functions documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/mystuff')
.onWrite(event => { 

   admin.database().ref('/myotherstuff').update({//values here});
});
```

Example:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/mystuff')
.onWrite(event => { 

   admin.database().ref('/myotherstuff').update({"username" : "hello, "coins" : 100});
});
```